# Is there a technical description of nav2d packages?

Tags: ros, nav2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I'm studyng on a project that is related to nav2d tutorials, and I want to understand the code for navigator.cpp (RobotNavigator.cpp) and LocalizerNode (selfLocalizer).

I can see the node connection to each other in rqt graph but is there a book, link that describe the codes in Block Diagram or Flow Chart how these two are designed theoretically ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225822/is-there-a-technical-description-of-nav2d-packages-?/) by [RosUser](https://answers.ros.org/users/25698/rosuser/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2016-02-04

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The LocalizerNode is just a wrapper around the particle filter used in [amcl](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl). You can check the documentation there, and there is also a lot of literature on localization methods, likely the best being [Probabilistic Robotics](http://www.probabilistic-robotics.org/).

To understand how the rest of nav2d works, please refer to the [Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/nav2d/Tutorials) and the [API](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/nav2d_navigator/html/classRobotNavigator.html)-Documentation.

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) with karma: 1658 on 2016-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RosUser](https://answers.ros.org/users/25698/rosuser/) on 2016-02-05**:
I have this book already and trying to understand Particle filter. I have been through the tutorials that was for more understand of launch files. But I did not know about amcl, Thanks :)